# Checkbox behaviour using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 3 checkbox and I want the following behaviour.

1. If I click in one checkbox, the others uncheck.
2. If I click in a checkbox that is checked, nothing happens.

I have this in jQuery:

```
('input.checkboxClassName').on('click', function() {
    $('input.checkboxClassName').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

I get #1, but not #2. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you click a checked, checkbox it will automatically uncheck. but you need to remains checked??

Comment: Use radio button instead.

Comment: Yes @RajaSekar, I need that when I click on the checkbox that is checked, it keeps checked. That way Im sure that always there's at least one checkbox checked

Comment: I can't @Azim, I've been asked to do with checkbox

Comment: A lot of people don't know the difference between a checkbox and a radio button. maybe the person who give you this order just don't know the name of the radio button and said checkbox instead

Comment: nop, he show me a word form to reproduce. But now that you say that, when I searched that question a lot of people propose using radio button, could you explain me why?

Comment: @Hugo because radiobuttons deliver you exactly this functionallity you're looking for but you don't need to use any JavaScript or jQuery at all

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.checkboxClassName').on('click', function(e){
   if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      e.preventDefault();
   } else {
      $('input.checkboxClassName').not(this).prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

This code will check whether the input box is already checked or not (in the if block).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jy0b83pq/1/

Comment: Not working, seems like does not enters the if because when I click gets unchecked

Comment: it works perfectly. Thanks you a lot @Mehul. Can you explain me what is the object e that you send?

Comment: @Hugo that is the event objected associated with the click. It just prevents the default event which is about to happen.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourcheckbox").click(function() {
        var checkBoxes = $("input[name=yourcheckboxname\\[\\]]");
        checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    });                 
});
```